# Flux Field Inline Fal mit CropVariants

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid, typo3-10.x

Iam currently updating a TYPO3 Project with Flux to TYPO3 10 and now i want to  migrate all fields to `FieldViewhelper`.

Mostly all Fields war pretty well but the Inline Fal elements with CropVariants are kinda tricky. I dont know how to implement this correctly inside the config option.

My Field currently look like this:

```html
{f:variable(name: '_allowedFileExtensions', value: '{allowedFileExtensions}')}
{f:variable(name: '_disallowedFileExtensions', value: '{disallowedFileExtensions}')}
<f:variable name="config" value="{
    type: 'inline',
    foreign_table: 'sys_file_reference',
    foreign_field: 'uid_foreign',
    foreign_sortby: 'sorting_foreign',
    foreign_table_field: 'tablenames',
    foreign_match_fields: {
        fieldname: name
    },
    foreign_label: 'uid_local',
    foreign_selector: 'uid_local',
    maxitems: maxitems,
    minitems: minitems,
    multiple: multiple,
    overrideChildTca: {
        columns: {
            uid_local: {
                config: {
                    appearance: {
                        elementBrowserType: 'file',
                        elementBrowserAllowed: _allowedFileExtensions
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        types: {
            0: {
                showitem: '--palette--;;imageoverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette'
            },
            1: {
                showitem: '--palette--;;imageoverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette'
            },
            2: {
                showitem: '--palette--;;imageoverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette'
            },
            3: {
                showitem: '--palette--;;audioOverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette'
            },
            4: {
                showitem: '--palette--;;videoOverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette'
            },
            5: {
                showitem: '--palette--;;imageoverlayPalette, --palette--;;filePalette'
            }
        }
    },
    filter: {
        0: {
            userFunc: 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\Filter\\FileExtensionFilter->filterInlineChildren',
            parameters: {
                allowedFileExtensions: _allowedFileExtensions,
                disallowedFileExtensions: _disallowedFileExtensions
            }
        }
    },
    appearance: {
        useSortable: 1,
        headerThumbnail: {
            field: 'uid_local',
            width: '45',
            height: '45c'
        },
        showPossibleLocalizationRecords: 0,
        showRemovedLocalizationRecords: 0,
        showSynchronizationLink: 0,
        showAllLocalizationLink: 0,
        enabledControls: {
            info: 1,
            new: 0,
            dragdrop: 1,
            sort: 0,
            hide: 1,
            delete: 1,
            localize: 1
        }
    }
}" />
<flux:field type="inline" name="{name}" label="{label}" config="{config}" exclude="0"/>
```

Theoretical i could do something like this; Thats the way i would do it in TCA Area below`overrideChildTca`:

```php
['columns']['crop']['config'] =>
'cropVariants' => [
  'heroimage' => [
     'title' => 'Hero Image',
     'allowedAspectRatios' => [
       '1504x846' => [
          'title' => '1504:846',
          'value' => 1504 / 846
        ],
     ],
  ],
],
```

I cant get it to work? Has somebody any ideas oder examples how to configure this correctly? Thank You!

Comment: Please write your question in English!

Comment: Did you try simply adding `cropVariants` to the `config` variable at the same level as `appearance`?

Comment: Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers\FieldViewHelper: cropVariants. Valid arguments are: type, name, label, exclude, config, transform, onChange, displayCond, inherit, inheritEmpty, extensionName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct writing for adding a crop variant for this example. If you add this part into `overrideChildTca` -> `columns` -> `crop` -> `config` then it should work :)

```php
    overrideChildTca: {
        columns: {
            crop: {
                config: {
                    type: 'imageManipulation',
                    cropVariants: {
                        tablet: {
                            title: 'Tablet',
                            allowedAspectRatios: {
                                NaN: {
                                    title: 'Free',
                                    value: 0.0
                                },
                                '21-9': {
                                    title: '21:9',
                                    value: 2.3333333
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

At least for `<flux.field.inline.fal>` and TYPO3 9.5 you can simply set the `cropVariants` via XML attribute:

```xml
<flux:field.inline.fal name="myField"
                       showThumbs="true"
                       cropVariants="{
                           default: {
                             title: 'Default',
                             allowedAspectRatios: {
                               default: {
                                 title: '1:1',
                                 value: '1'
                               }
                             }
                           }
                         }"/>
```

Comment: Yes thats correct. I am currently doing that. Thats pretty simple. This works in TYPO3 10 aswell, but its deprecated and will be removed in Flux 10.0 
https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/blob/development/Classes/ViewHelpers/Field/Inline/FalViewHelper.php

Comment: `<flux:field.inline.fal>` is not deprecated anymore.

Comment: @cweiske Do you have a source for us?

Comment: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1889